# How to code in openerp so that user can create his fields?

Tags: python, odoo

I have been developing modules in OpenERP-7 using Python on Ubuntu-12.04. I want to give my users a feature by which they will have the ability to create what ever fields they want to . Like they will set the name, data_type etc for the field and then on click , this field will be created. I dont have any idea how this will be implemented. I have set up mind to create a button that will call a function and it will create a new field according to the details entered by the user . Is this approach of mine is right or not? And will this work . ? Please guide me so that I can work smartly.

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The user can add fields, models, can customize the views etc from client side. These are in `Settings/Technical/Database Structure`, here you can find the menus Fields, Models etc where the user can add fields. And the views can be customized in `Settings/Technical/User Interface`.

Comment: Doing this , the user will have to define the view everytime which is not needed here. All I want is to set name, type and save the details to create a new field.